# "Perfect matching" en français

Tags: traduction, anglais

> There is a perfect matching.

Essayant de traduire cette phrase en français j'ai trouvé les options :

> Il y a une adéquation parfaite.
>
> Il y a un appariement parfait.
>
> Il y a une correspondance parfaite.

Je me demande si elles sont équivalentes. Y a-t-il d'autres façons de dire la même chose ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

J'aurais opté pour la réponse

> Il y a une correspondance parfaite

Car ici, on parle bien de 2 objets de même types, qui vont ensemble / se ressemblent.

Adéquation est plus utilisé pour parler de deux choses qui ne sont pas du même type, mais qui vont bien ensemble.

> Une parfaite adéquation entre ses paroles et ses actes.

Apparier s'utilise plus dans le cas où l'on doit former des paires sur une multitude d'objets.

> Faire un appariement de ses chaussettes.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about the technical mathematical term *perfect matching* used in graph theory, [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couplage_(th%C3%A9orie_des_graphes)) says that the translation is

> il y a un couplage parfait

or

> il y a un couplage complet.

Googling seems to show that *couplage parfait* is by far the more common term for  *perfect matching* in the graph theory sense. This makes sense, because *perfect matching* is also far more common than its synonym *complete matching* in English.

Comment: The fact that **the** Peter Shor come here to answer random question about French is one of the reason I love this network.

Comment: @Evpok: I don't generally answer *random* questions about French ... I don't know enough French to answer most of the questions here.

Comment: Ok, *determined* questions then. Still cool :-)

Comment: Professor Shor, thank you very much for your answer!